What is the algorithm behind the whites slider in lightroom?
I'm trying to replicate lightroom's behavior when increasing the value of the whites slider within a GLSL shader. I've come close, but it feels like there is a hue or saturation adjustment that is missing. I'm not interested in the behavior when decreasing the slider.
I've tried a lot of variations but haven't hit it yet. I also tested with grabbing the absolute value of the difference between an edited and unedited image of a stepped gradient, which is how I came up with the magic numbers.
I also noticed that when differencing the images, it produced a partially inverted version of the source, so I suspect the inverted source may be used in some way. When I was not using the inverted source, my outputs would come out with an unwanted color cast.
Here's what I have:
// color is rgb input
// whites is 0 - 1 amount of effect.
vec3 adjustWhites(vec3 color, float whites) {
    
    // Create inverted version
    vec3 inverted = 1.0 - color;
    
    // Get luminance of original color
    float luminance = dot(color, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));

    // Create gradient - using some magic numbers here
    float grad = smoothstep(0.6, 0.0, abs(luminance - 0.62));
    grad = pow(grad, 1.8);

    // Blend bright colors back in
    return color * vec3(1.0 + grad * inverted * whites);
}

I know it's also possible they could be using a dynamic white or black point for these calculations, but I wasn't able to find any literature about this specific feature. I'd love if someone could help explain the math behind this slider or point me towards a blog post or white paper.
